# How can I see an the output of my C programs using Dev-C++?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I'm looking to follow along with *The C Programming Language (Second Addition)* on a machine running Vista.

So far, I've found Dev-C++ the easiest IDE to do this in. However, I still have one problem. Whenever I run my compiled code, for example: a simple hello world program, it runs, but the console window just flickers on the screen, and I can't see the output.

How can I see an the output of my C programs using Dev-C++? I found a C++ specific solution, `System("pause")`, and a really ugly C solution, `while` looping `fflush(stdout)`, but nothing nice and pretty.

Comment: Have you considered a more up to date IDE? Dev-C++ hasn't had an update in 5 years.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't more than 5 years? I used it to learn C++ in like 2004 and I got told it was out of date then!  (Also, `System` is not C++ specific. That will work on both C and C++, though it should be avoided because it's platform specific)

Comment: What IDE should I be using then?

Comment: Which has the exact same issue.

Comment: @nobugz: Not if you run from the IDE without the debugger; and if you use the debugger, you can simple set a breakpoint at the end.  But that is not the only good reason to use VC++2008 Express over Dev-C++

Comment: Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/) is another IDE alternative.  The console that runs your programs is integrated into the IDE so it doesn't disappear after the program terminates.

Comment: Code::Blocks is another option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows when a process terminates, the OS closes the associated window.  This happens with all programs (and is generally desirable behaviour), but people never cease to be surprised when it happens to the ones they write themselves.

I am being slightly harsh perhaps; many IDE's execute the user's process in a shell as a child process, so that it does not own the window so it won't close when the process terminates.  Although this would be trivial, Dev-C++ does not do that.

Be aware that when Dev-C++ was popular, this question appeard at least twice a day on Dev-C++'s own forum on Sourceforge.  For that reason the forum has a "Read First" thread that provides a suggested solution amongst solutions to many other common problems.  You should read it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dev-cpp/forums/forum/48211/topic/1693710).

Note that Dev-C++ is somewhat old and no longer actively maintained.  It suffers most significantly from an almost unusable and very limited debugger integration.  Traffic on the Dev-C++ forum has been dropping off since the release of VC++ 2005 Express, and is now down to a two or three posts a week rather than the 10 or so a day it had in 2005.  All this suggest that you should consider an alternative tool IMO.

Comment: Update: Dev-C++ has been forked as [Orwell Dev-C++](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.co.uk/) which is under current maintenance.  Whether it solves other issues with Dev-C++ I cannot say.

Comment: @avgvstvs : Where?  The [original project](http://www.bloodshed.net/dev/devcpp.html) has not been updated in years and is still distributed with [MinGW-GCC 3.4.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/changes.html).  The [Orwell Dev-C++ fork](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.co.uk/) was last updated April 2015 and  is distributed with TDM-GCC 4.9.2.  Chugging is perhaps the right word - it is hardly a hive of activity.  Since writing this answer several free tools from Microsoft and others have been released that are more up-to-date.  The Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition makes Dev-C++ look stone age.

Comment: I found the Orwell fork, which as you say hasn't been updated since 2015.  I blindly assumed that meant that someone had took over maintenance since 2010

Answer (score 6):

I put a `getchar()` at the end of my programs as a simple "pause-method".  Depending on your particular details, investigate `getchar`, `getch`, or `getc`

Comment: IMHO, changing your code to work around a strange behavior in your editing environment doesn't seem like the best way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

Use `#include conio.h`

Then add `getch();` before `return 0;`

Comment: the conio.h header file is not portable (only found on a windows platform) so should not be used.  Rather use only functions found in the C library.  like `while( int ch = getchar() && EOF != ch && '\n' != ch );   getchar();`  which cleans out stdin, then waits for the user to enter a final char

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to run your program directly instead of through the IDE.  Open a command prompt (Start->Run->`Cmd.exe`->Enter), `cd` to the folder where your project is, and run the program from there.  That way, when the program exits, the prompt window sticks around and you can read all of the output.

Alternatively, you can also re-direct standard output to a file, but that's probably not what you are going for here.

Answer (score 2):

For Dev-C++, the bits you need to add are:-

At the Beginning

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

And at the point you want it to stop - i.e. before at the end of the program, but before the final }

```
system("PAUSE");
```

It will then ask you to "Press any key to continue..."

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the web site didn't like the "include" line.... You need to put a "hash" before include then <stdlib.h>

Comment: Why advise `system("pause")` when portable and efficient ways exist?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your header file        #include 
and then in the end add this line :   getch();

Answer (score 1):

You can open a command prompt (Start -> Run -> `cmd`, use the `cd` command to change directories) and call your program from there, or add a `getchar()` call at the end of the program, which will wait until you press Enter. In Windows, you can also use `system("pause")`, which will display a "Press enter to continue..." (or something like that) message.

Answer (score 1):

Add a line `getchar();` or `system("pause");` before your `return 0;` in main function.
It will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

; 
It works...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
   int x,y; // (Or whatever variable you want you can)
```

your required process syntax type here then;

```
   cout << result
```

(or your required output result statement); use without space in getchar and other syntax.

```
   getchar();
}
```

Now you can save your file with .cpp extension and use ctrl + f 9 to compile and then use ctrl + f 10 to execute the program.
It will show you the output window and it will not vanish with a second Until you click enter to close the output window.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should link your project in console mode

just press Ctrl+h and in General tab select console.

Answer (score 0):

When a program is not showing or displaying an output on the screen, using `system("pause");` is the solution to it on a Windows profile.

Answer (score 0):

The use of line `system("PAUSE")` will fix that problem and also include the pre processor directory `#include<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you are  writing a c program and want the output log to stay instead of flickering away you only need to import the stdlib.h header file and type "system("PAUSE");" at the place you want the output screen to halt.Look at the **example** here.The following simple c program prints the product of 5 and 6 i.e 30 to the output window and halts the output window.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
 {
      int a,b,c;
      a=5;b=6;
      c=a*b;
      printf("%d",c);
      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
 }
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: The same option is expressed in the question.